# ReactJS react-app-rewired / config-overrides for raw-loader not working

Tags: reactjs, raw-loader

I'd like to use the [raw-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) in my react js project. 
I'm using the [react-app-rewired](https://medium.com/@ryoldash/customize-webpack-config-of-react-app-created-with-create-react-app-7a78c7849edc) lib and a config-overrides.js.

When I import the file, I'm hoping to receive the contents of it.
Instead, I'm receiving the path to the file.

```
App.js

import toolboxsrc from './Blockly/toolbox.xml.raw';
....

// setting a prop of a component
toolboxsrc={toolboxsrc}

~ ~ ~ ~ ~
config-overrides.js

module.exports = function override(config, env) {    
    config.module.rules.push (
          {
            test: /\.raw$/i,
            loader: 'raw-loader',
          }
    )

    return config;
}
```

I'm using the command 
`"start": "react-app-rewired start --scripts-version react-scripts"`

There are no errors in the compilation, but the prop is being set to `/static/media/toolbox.xml.93a6d25d.raw` instead of the hoped-for contents of the file.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @curly_brackets -- see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to add a raw loader directive to the source. This also requires a compile-time directive:

```
/* eslint import/no-webpack-loader-syntax: off */
import textFile from '!!raw-loader!./assets/textFile.txt';
```